# How to get the duration of scheduled live?

Tags: dailymotion-api

When we scheduled a live video session with a start time and a duration, we can get the start_time through the API but we can't get the duration. So when the live session is ended, the video status in the API is still in mode "live", with a start_time, no end_time.. 
How can we know the live session is ended ?
Thanks
best regards
frederic

Answer (score 0):

Good point, the `duration` field is not relevant for live streaming videos but only for VOD. We will fix it as soon as possible. For now, to check if whether a live session is ended or not, you can simply use the `onair` field:

[image]